# Is this a common design pattern? "Descriptor pattern"?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is what I'm doing below a common design pattern? If so, what's the name?

I have a complex object that has "simple" fields like Strings and lists of Strings, as well as other complex objects. I want to add instances of this object to a JMS message queue, which means they need to be `Serializable`. I don't want to make the entire object graph `Serializable`, so I've chosen instead to make "Descriptor" objects that contain the necessary information to build the complex objects and "Builder" objects that can create the objects. Now, I serialize the "Descriptor" object and add it to the queue. When the object is dequeued, it is built into a full-fledged object using the "Builder".

An important note  to make is that the objects are jobs that are run on other systems. The message queue is one way and serialization only happens at the beginning of the lifecycle of the job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most similar pattern to the one you implemented seems the **Memento** pattern.

In that case it's used to store the state of an object into a **Memento** object while anything can modify the original object and allows you to restore the old state by using the *Memento* as a "previous state" of your object.

In your case you don't need to store a snapshot of the object to modify the original one but just as a lightweight version of the serializable value of itself so it's not exactly the same things but quite similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and short explanation.

Answer (score 5):

To me this sounds like you implemented (part of) the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).